# Notification not making sound or vibration?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am making a program and I want the app to make a notification. When the notification goes off then only the ticker text is displayed. No sound or vibration or light is accompanied with it.

Here is an example of my code:

```
int icon = R.drawable.icon;  
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Context context = getApplicationContext();      

CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";  
CharSequence contentText = "Countdown Complete!";

Intent intent = new Intent();
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, myCountDown.getName() + " is completed!", System.currentTimeMillis());

long[] vibrate = {0,100,200,300};
notification.vibrate = vibrate;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(myCountDown.getId(), notification);
```

Answer (score 8):

To add notification light you need to add this(notice the .flags, not .defaults):

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
notification.ledARGB=0xffffffff; //color, in this case, white
notification.ledOnMS=1000; //light on in milliseconds
notification.ledOffMS=4000; //light off in milliseconds
```

For default sound:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

For default vibration pattern:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

For vibration, as Dean Thomas mentioned, you'll need a permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`

Answer (score 3):

To make the LED work, you need to tell it what to do.

```
   notification.ledOnMS = 1000; //Be on for a second
   notification.ledOffMS = 1000; //Be off for a second
   notification.ledARGB = Color.GREEN; //What colour should the LED be?
```

To make the vibrate work, you need permission added to your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you ensure the device is not muted and actually has a notification sound picked by the user (also not silent)?

Another thing to try would be:

```
[Note obj].sound = value
[Note obj].LEDARGB = value
[Note obj].vibrate = value
```

Comment: Yes the sound is on and i picked a sound ding when the notification goes off. i will try the code and see if that works.

Comment: i tried this and realized this is what im doing atleast for the vibrate and my code should inform the notification manager to use the defaults for the lights and sound... So it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I find there is a `setDefaults` method in  `NotificationCompat.Builder` , and it provides you for adjusting notification preferences.
Here is an example:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.taiwanpic)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle("AAAAA")
            .setContentText("BBBBB")
            .setSubText("CCCCC")
            .setContentInfo("DDDDD")
            .setTicker("EEEEE")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();

notificationManager.notify(pid, builder.build());
```

If you don't use all default values, you can also try `DEFAULT_SOUND`, `DEFAULT_VIBRATE`,`DEFAULT_LIGHTS` as you want.